# What are the possible values returned by setlocale(LC_CTYPE, NULL)?

Tags: c, character-encoding, locale

I need to read data from command-line and store data in UTF-8. In order to do that, my approach is to determine which charset is using the command-line shell by retrieving the current locale. (Of course, if you see a better approach, please share your thoughts!)

What values should be expected when trying to detect the `LC_CTYPE` value for the active locale?

I am using the function below, which expects to get either a string like '`POSIX`' or '`C`', or something like '`en_US.UTF-8`'.

Does anyone know if there are other possible situations (i.e. possible values)?

(My concern being to make sure I handle all cases)

```
/* Retrieve the current charset using setlocale function.
 @return Returned value is a string holding the name of the current charset.  On error, function returns NULL. 
*/
char* get_charset() {
    // read environment locale for LC_CTYPE category
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");
    char* locale = setlocale(LC_CTYPE, NULL);    
    if (strstr(locale, ".") != NULL) {
      // return codeset (last block of chars preceeded by a dot)
      return strrchr(locale, '.')+1;
    }
    return locale;
}
```

Comment: Best to treat the locale as a free-form string instead of expecting it to conform to any particular pattern, as it's entirely OS dependent.

Comment: @Shawn : thanks! Actually what I need is to find out which is the charset used for the input (updated the question). Do you see another way to achieve that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, POSIX defines a ["Portable character set"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_character_set) which is a subset of ASCII, and that is supposed to be part of any standard-compliant character set.

As for the `setlocale()` function, the [official GNU documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/setlocale.html) states that when [XPG syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Locale-Names.html) is not used by the platform (i.e. OS), "C" is the fallback value and means "POSIX compliant".
Besides, the returned value is a char pointer (`char*`), so result should always be either a string or `NULL`.

So, here are the answers to the question:

1. Yes. The given snippet should cover all situations.
2. If the idea is to store the result in UTF-8, no conversion is required in case the `get_charset()` function returns 'C', since that means the used charset is compatible with ASCII which, in turn, is compatible with UTF-8